# Cannot find PostgreSQL installation

Tags: postgresql, macos

I installed PostgreSQL version 11.1 from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), and went through the entire installation process and was notified that my the installation directory was /Library/PostrgeSQL/11. At the end of the process, the dialog said that the installation process was successful. This was confirmed when I re-launched the installer:

[image]

I looked at the Library directory in a new instance of Terminal and ran the command to view all hidden files and it didn't show up, as follows:

[image]

Where is the folder that was installed?

Comment: You installed in `/Library/PostgreSQL` but are trying to find it in `~/Library/PostgreSQL`. `/Library` (at the root of the disk) and `~/Library` (in your home directory) are two entirely different directories.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are correct